# $k$-compositions of $n$ with parts equal to $1$ or $2$ and Fibonacci Sequence

Tags: combinatorics, fibonacci-numbers

I am trying to understand the following problem:

Let $f_n = \{(a_1,\ldots ,a_k=n) \mid  a_1+\ldots +a_k=n \text{ with }a_i = 1 \text { or }2 \}$ i.e., $f_n$ is the set of all k composition of n s.t its parts are equal to 1 or 2. Prove $f_{n+1} = f_n + f_{n-1} $ for $n \geq 1 $. $f_n$ is the nth fibonacci number. What are we trying to prove exactly?

Thanks.

Comment: It’s difficult to count all decomposition of $n$ using only $1$ or $2$ but if you can prove that the decomposition is equal to Fibonacci number then you can compute it easily. You can prove it using recurrence relation.

Comment: In other words prove that cardinality $|f_n|$ satisfies the same initial conditions and recurrence relation that defines the fibonacci sequence.  Are you familiar with that?

Comment: Thanks to both. I am familiar with recurrence relations. So @hardmath, you are saying that i need to prove that $|f_n| = |f_{n-1}| + |f_{n-2}|$ for n>1?

Comment: Indeed, and verify the initial conditions (values for $|f_1|,|f_2|$).

Comment: Thank you @hardmath. My last question (i think) would be that, since the proof i need to do must be a combinatorial one, how could i assure |f(n)| = |f(n-1)| + |f(n-2)| without using induction?

Comment: You need to think about constructing compositions that add up to $n$ with restricted summands from ones that add to $n-1$ and $n-2$ respectively.